# Questions about sensing pulse current and driving a logic MOSFET in a circuit

Tags: mosfet, current-measurement, mosfet-driver

This question is about a personal project and related to my [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/309834/a-question-on-current-sensing-through-a-very-low-resistor) but focusing on different issues or questions. By increasing the shunt resistor from 1 mOhm to 330 mOhm I wanted to avoid using a special amplifier like in my previous question.

A uC's PWM output will control 2A to 6A current through a heating-wire and since the resistance might change, the current value roughly will be fed back to ADC of the uC for regulation ect. The circuit will be soldered on a perfboard.

For minimalism, I decided to use a single-supply op amp and low-side sensing to avoid common-mode-voltage related issues.

For clarity I will write down the questions one by one in detail:

**1-)** [This](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1279415) article examines the use of op amp, difference-amplifier and instrumentation amplifier for this purpose. What I first understand is, if I use a difference-amplifier or an instrumentation amplifier I have to use a split-supply(or maybe some reference voltage techniques which will reduce the range I don't know actually). Since the only option left for me is an op amp option, the article mentions the following issue for that case:

> The drawbacks to low-side sensing are disturbances to the system
>   load’s ground potential and the inability to detect load shorts.
>   Figure 2 depicts a typical low-side sensing scenario.

And below Rp or Vp illustrates this:

[image]

My question is, in my application would that be an issue as well? I mean I can live with 100mA error. I couldn't find a topology where I can use a single difference amplifier with a single-supply. Is that possible? Or how can I minimise the error introduced by ground?

**2-)** I used LM358 as an active filter with unity gain and it follows another LM358 as an amplifier with a gain of two(to match 0 to 5V range to the ADC).

Green is the swept PWM voltage across Rsense; blue is the output of the active filter with LM358 and the red is the final output. Is LM358 proper for this application? And is 0.33 Ohm shunt resistor is high enough?

**3-)** Basically the question is do I need a gate driver for this MOSFET(for power dissipation concerns)? According to the [data sheet](http://info.incomp.hu/NETPDF/IRL3803.pdf) this is a logic MOSFET. But still some in my previous question told me I still need a driver for since the MOSFET has capacitance which will drive excessive current.

But one of the commentators told me that I need a special driver such as [this one](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uc3705.pdf). But the rest didn't find it as an issue. So I'm confused how to drive this MOSFET properly. Here is what LTspice shows the MOSFET's power at %95 PWM:
[image]

**Edit:**
[image]
[image]

Comment: Soliciting opinions is off topic. This is a q and a site. Try being specific and clear about your questions.

Comment: Omg I spent an hour to be clear, if you still think my question is unclear I think thats my capacity. Im sorry.

Comment: I jumped to the bottom and read your request so it's worth deleting the opinions and suggestion bit. I'll read the rest!

Comment: Alright I deleted that part maybe better format now.

Comment: 1) start-point ground right at the 330mOhm shunt terminal, 2) Lm358 includes GND as common mode, and runs on +12, 3) what is your PWM frequency if its a few kHz I wouldn't be too concerned

Comment: Also don't forget I^2R, (6)^2 *0.33 = 10.8 Watts...

Comment: @sstobbe Do you mean the GND of Rsense should be very close to the power supply ground? Is that all I should take care of?

Comment: @doncarlos when you build the circuit connect all your analog/digital grounds right to Rsense lead (not to the power supply negative), that way all your control circuitry doesn't see the Rp as you showed in your one schematic.

Comment: Star-point ground http://imgur.com/a/NLGiV

Comment: @sstobbe You mean this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/lg3MY.png I made the drawing to be sure

Comment: Yes your drawing is correct, it is how it is physically connected that is import the blue line connects to the resistor lead not at the power supply terminal

Comment: @sstobbe Thanks, but I have one more thing worries me. I will buy an accurate 5Watt 50mOhm shunt resistor something like this one: http://eu.mouser.com/images/bourns/lrg/PWR44122S.jpg But when I solder one of this resistor's terminal to Opamp non-inverting input(as in the circuit). do you think the resistor's heat will affect/reach the opamp by conduction?

Comment: Your intuition is correct that heat may have an impact and there will be a 10's - 100's uV level thermal EMF due to temperature gradient but this a few orders of magnitude below your full-scale output. Opamp doesn't have to be physical close. The key is to make Kelvin connections to the shunt.

Comment: @sstobbe By Kelvin connection you mean something like this?: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3xCR.png I draw this to be more clear. Would this prevent heat conduction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)  in my application would that be an issue as well?

Maybe yes, maybe no. If you want good accuracy you can use this approach, but you have to be very careful about routing your signals. If you make your power connection right next to the return end of your load, and also put the ground connection of your sense resistor very close to that point, you should be OK. 6 amps is (by hobby standards) a pretty hefty current, but it's not outrageous.

2a) Is LM358 proper for this application?

Yes, and it's a good choice as long as you're using cheap, readily available op amps. It's input configuration allows inputs right down to ground, and that is important in this circuit. There simply aren't a lot of this-generation op amps which will do the job.

2b) And is 0.33 Ohm shunt resistor is high enough?

Actually, .33 is probably a bit too large. As I mentioned in your previous question, at 1 mohm 6 amps produces 6 mV, which does not appreciably affect the MOSFET. At .33 ohms, full on current is about 2 volts, as you recognize. The thing is, assuming you're using a 3.3 volt MCU to provide your PWM, assuming 3 volts for the output to the gate of the FET means that the gate-source voltage is only 1 volt when on. This is the nominal turn-on voltage for your FET (Vgs(th), or gate-source turn-on voltage threshold - look it up in your data sheet), and the threshold is usually set at a very low current, such as 250 uA or 1 mA. So you need more voltage to drive the FET to handle 6 amps. If you drop the sense resistor you'll have less sense voltage which will give you more gate voltage margin, but you'll also need more gain in your conditioning circuitry, and the circuit will be more sensitive to stray resistances in the ground path.

This leads to

3) do I need a gate driver for this MOSFET(for power dissipation concerns)?

Well, if you give the gate enough voltage, I'd guess that you'll be OK in terms of dissipation. But a driver is a very good idea, especially if you keep the sense resistor at .33 ohms. Like, a very, very good idea. If you're using a 5 volt MCU, I'd guess you don't need a driver.

Comment: +1 for the effect that too high a source resistor will start to turn off the mosfet on high currents.

Comment: Thanks I updated the circuit. Please see my edit. PWM freq. will be 500Hz and 0/5V pulses not 3.3V. But for a better Vgs I listen your suggestion and reduced to Rsense to 50mOhm which at 6A dissipates 2Watt at 100%PWM. So it make sense to reduce Resense. I wanted to replace LM358 with an opamp with much better input offset voltage but the best result for the active filter for some reason is with LM358 so I will stick with it. I also increased R_nichrome to 1.9Ohm to set the current amplitude at 6A. So as far as I understand at this freq (500Hz)and this Vgs setting I dont need any driver right?

Comment: I think we are missing a point here about freq. Freq. of the uC can be low like 500Hz but when I adjust the duty cycle very low like %1 or very high I think that will be a problem. Triggering MOSFET at 500Hz with %50 duty is not the same thing triggering 500Hz with %1 duty. But maybe still harmless 25mA. Just wanted to point out

Comment: @doncarlos - I don't understand your concern, but reread my original response. The way you drive the MOSFET gate will cause inaccuracy at low duty cycle. The simple solution is a MOSFET driver IC.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I really want to keep it simple so if not needed I dont want to use an extra IC. I meant my application will not use PMW at duties less than %30 so I dont think it would be problem. Btw I want to replace LM358 opamps with LMC6482. LMC6482 has less input offset voltage and it is rail to rail.

Comment: @doncarlos - I don't see a problem with replacing 2 transistors and 3 resistors with an 8-bin IC.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I think you are right, I will go for a dedicated driver anyway(so I can drive at higher freq. with less ripple on active filter side). I will use 50mOhm for the shunt. But I hope I can get the similar results with the simulation in real for the current sensing part. I will use LMC6482. At active filter for 1uC caps I should not use electrolytic caps right? I was thinking of x7r ceramic caps.

Answer (score 2):

1) try and keep the opamp that senses the resistor close to that resistor. Tee off all circuit 0 volts from the bottom of that resistor i.e. use star pointing techniques where you can.

2) you can use a lower value resistor with more gain in the second opamp stage of course. Going higher than 3.3 ohms might mean it starts to burn or get too hot. Don't go too low or the input offset voltage errors from the LM358 will start to be significant.

3) if you are only running at a few kHz max then it's unlikely you'll need a specific driver for the mosfet but do check the data sheet and look at the graph for drain current versus DS voltage for various gate levels. This will tell you if your gate drive level is high enough. Specific gate drivers tend to be required in the hundreds of kHz in order to charge and discharge the gate capacitance fast enough.

Comment: I modified the circuit please see my edit. I lowered the Rsense to 50mOhm(Is that an okay value for offset error issue?) and increased the gain of the second stage. For the active filter any other op amp than LM358 in simulation gave worse result. Even the ones with very low input offset voltage. But regarding your 1st answer; do you mean that the ground of the Rsense should be very close to the GND of the 12V power supply? If so, in practice how long max?  Maybe I dig it too much but never tried such circuit before and cannot find anymore practical information quantitatively.

Comment: The 12 volt power supply can be feet away but once you decide where 0 volts is, stick to it and make that your star point. The logical place is at the low voltage end of the sense resistor.

Comment: What do you mean by starpoint. Could you draw a simple illustration about what you say if possible it would help a lot, Im very curious if I get it right?

Comment: You'll find pictures if you google it. Basically it means that any connection to 0 volts connects to the single unambiguous star point independently (as far as practical of course). Clearly those 0volt connections that carry micro amps can share a limb with other low current connections. The whole point is that you define where your 0 volt reference is and sensitive to connections do not share a wire or path with the 6 amps or pwm signals.

Comment: Alright hopefully I think I got it, just to be sure now Im drawing it. Its a bit highish current stuff so thats why I want to be more sure before I solder

Comment: This is what you meant right? https://i.stack.imgur.com/lg3MY.png

Comment: Not good enough because your pwm driver is sharing the same grounding wire as your measurement amplifier. Anything on the fet side needs to be on a separate limb of the star point ideally.

Comment: Okay like this you mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMYHV.png Sorry for misunderstandings..

Comment: Or you mean every single GND should be separately joint at a certain point like this: https://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/high-power-device-and-the-arduino-also-hi-i%27m-new-here-)/?action=dlattach;attach=301028;image ?

Comment: That is a good picture of star pointing. At first you follow this general rule, as you should now, then, as you learn you start to recognise short cuts and ways of connecting islands of 0 volts through one connection to the star point but, at the moment, you should follow that picture.

Comment: See C4 and C5 forming an island with he associated driver. That's an example of where you can take a short cut. See how the driver and fet have labels saying keep short. That could form another island of course but, until you get it intuitively you might as well just follow the basic rule and try short cuts out later.

Comment: I adapted this idea to my circuit in my question . Here I draw by hand on a paper: http://i.imgur.com/z3XDnfB.jpg. I could only find 1 island. I guess this must be what you mean, thanks for help. Practice is sooo hard to find

Comment: There are things missing from the circuit so I can't realistically say. Sorry but looking at star pointing techniques is an all or nothing analysis.

Comment: @doncarlos Are you happy with an answer posted? If so then formally accept one of them or raise a comment please.